# How can I configure the Material Icon Theme to use default icons for some folders in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons

How can I configure the Material Icon Theme to use default icons for some folders in VS Code?

E.g. I have a folder named `trigger` and that folder has an unusual icon. I would like to have a default icon for the `trigger` folder, just as it is for the sibling `shoot` folder.

[image]

I read through the features of the Material Icon Theme inside the VS Code documentation, but was not able to find a way to achieve what I want.

I mean [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme) extension.

Also, I was able to disable all speicific icons styling by using the `Material Icons: Change Folder Theme` command. But I want to disable only for a specific folder, or at least for a specific folder name (`trigger` in my case).

Comment: for Color Themes we have customization in `settings.json`, if there is nothing similar for Icon Themes then a feature request would be useful

Answer (score 3):

Just declare in your settings.json file:

```
"material-icon-theme.folders.associations": {
    "trigger": ""
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In the settings of the extension there's a option to set the icons of the folders. By default it's set on "specific", you need to set it on "classic".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gybh.png)

Comment: I think that you should edit your answer to show where/how to change it. It wod make it better